# Uncaught ReferenceError with cakePHP

Tags: html, jquery, cakephp

I have a "Uncaught ReferenceError" for the getPackages method (declared in a controller) in the following cakePHP code:

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $this->element('cropKindInput', [
                    'onChange' => 
                       "getPackages($('#sample-category-id').val(), 
                                    $('#crop-kind-id').val(),  
                                    $('#seed-category-id').val(),'variety-name')",
                    'options' => [
                        'required' => 'required',
                        'label' => ['class' => 'required', 'text' => 'Crop Kind'],
                    ]]);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As I checked, the error comes because Jquery is not loaded before the call. But in the Head I have:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

which is the solution I've found a couple of times. I'm new to cakePHP, can anyone suggest a solution to this please?

Comment: I don't think your issue has anything to do with Cake, except in that the HTML you're generating from your Cake application isn't doing what you expect. How and where and when to load jQuery in your HTML is a separate question; if you know how jQuery is supposed to be loaded, and a stand-alone page works when you do it that way, but you can't figure out how to get Cake to load it in that spot, only then does it become something to be tagged for Cake.

Comment: Hi @GregSchmidt, the html code generated is fine. Additional cake code in the same page is generating html and checking that the document is loaded, and works fine. I've tried to include the code to check the document is loaded for this problem but for some reason it's refreshing the page all the time, and I guess I understand why. As I'm starting with CakePHP, it's also difficult to explain what's going on. I'll carry on investigating this problem. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If it was fine, it would be working. If it's not working, then there's something wrong with the HTML. You can't fix the Cake code that's generating the output unless you know what, specifically, is wrong with the output.

Comment: The problem has been solved by adding the 'onChange', passed  to the element, in a JQuery at the bottom of the page. The were no problem with the HTML generated by cake but it was executed before the page was load. It is working now. Thanks